# How should rhetorical questions be punctuated?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should rhetorical questions end with a period?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12760/should-rhetorical-questions-end-with-a-period)

How would you punctuate the following sentence, and others like it? Are there any precedents, or applicable style guides?

> The question is what are we going to do about it?

No rephrasing, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should rhetorical questions end with a period?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12760/should-rhetorical-questions-end-with-a-period) or [How to punctuate a quoted rhetorical interrogative sentence that ends a declarative sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79258/how-to-punctuate-a-quoted-rhetorical-interrogative-sentence-that-ends-a-declarat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a direct question expressed within a declarative sentence that declares the question to be a question. We answered this last week. The sentence should be written one of two ways:

> The question is, "What are we going to do about it?"

or

> The question is: "What are we going to do about it?"

There are some other possibilities, but these are the two major contenders.

This is not a rhetorical question unless there is no answer or unless the answer has already been provided and you're not asking for a real answer. In any case, it doesn't affect the orthography or punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd low-end the punctuation:

> The question is, what are we going to do about it?

Or

> The question is, *what are we going to do about it?*

While the quotation marks may seem necessary, this is a common enough construction that they really aren't required unless you are writing something extremely formal.

Comment: I specialize in formal expository prose for publication in international medical and technical journals, but I agree with JAM that his two versions are fine for informal writing. Nobody consults style manuals for informal writing. I don't blame them. Neither do I. Always consider your audience as well as your vehicle (informal: letter, email, etc.; formal: journal article, dissertation, university class paper, etc.).

Comment: A compromise between the high-end punctuation offered by @BillFranke and what's offered here by JAM might be to capitalize the 'W' but leave out the quotes, as in, _The question is: What are we going to do about it?_ According to [one website](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/colon.htm), "If the introductory phrase preceding the colon is very brief and the clause following the colon represents the real business of the sentence, begin the clause after the colon with a capital letter."

Comment: @J.R.: Good suggestion. +1

Comment: Three good suggestions. I would accept them all if I could.

Comment: @Emre: But you can't. The question is: Which one are you going to use? :^)

Comment: @J.R. great suggestion -- that's how I'll punctuate rhetorical questions from now on.