# Ask question without using "?" in it

Tags: sentence, question-mark

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it appropriate to end a question without a question mark?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35806/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-question-without-a-question-mark)

I have heard so many times people use two way of asking question? Is there any way to ask question where you will not find the question but a sentence to ask question?

Comment: Huh? A question without a question?

Comment: Questions normally require question marks. It's possible to create a dialogue in which a question's asked without actually phrasing it as a question but as an answer; eg, A: _My philosophy teacher asked if I would sleep with her for $1000_. B: _And you, of course, said "Absolutely!"_  Speaker B is either making an assumption that A agreed or implicitly asking A to answer the unstated question: _And what did you say?_ Why would B not ask? Because B wants to project confidence that he or she knows A well enough to know what A would say. The question mark isn't there but implied. Not normal.

Comment: I'm not happy the way you asked that question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

English requires direct questions be followed by a question mark. However, there are many ways you can solicit information without asking a question, and then a question mark isn't used because a direct question wasn't asked. For example:

> What is the weather like?
>   I wonder what the weather is like.
>
> What time is it?
>   I wish I knew what time it was.
>
> How much does that cost?
>   I'd like to know how much that costs.
>
> What is it?
>   Please tell me what it is.