# Is it imperative or interrogative?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is it imperative , interrogative or what ? 
A question I got online asks, " What is the simple subject of the following sentences ?
is the sentence imperative or interrogative ?

question 17 : Will you check the tires. 
using a( full stop) not a question mark. 
First, is it correct or wrong to start with ( will) and ending the sentence with a full stop ? 
OR perhaps it is mistyping, but it is not the only question

It is already a request ( polite command ) but how it doesn't end in a question mark ? 
[image]

Comment: If you're only dealing with writing, use the punctuation. Questions have question marks. That's all you need to know to answer this rather silly question.

Comment: @JohnLawler - The one oddball is 17.

Comment: There should be a question mark if it's a question, and otherwise one's imagination decides what it sposta be. If the _Will_ is stressed, it's a rather peeved suggestion, though not an imperative. Like I said, it's a silly question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suggestion phrased as a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54154/suggestion-phrased-as-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

***It is already a request ( polite command ) but how it doesn't end in a question mark ?***

Question 17 is a courtesy question, (as defined by The Chicago Manual of Style, fifteenth edition 2003), and as such does not require a question mark:

> 6.74 Courtesy question. A request courteously disguised as a question does not require a question mark.
>
> [Relevant example:] Will the audience please rise.

So it is not really a question but a polite request, as you can see from the example above which takes a more or less identical form.

Reference: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/262363/187344

***Is it imperative , interrogative or what ?***

I think the way in which the request was 'disguised' as a question here is what confused you, but as this is a request it is imperative.

> Imperative Sentences
>
> The third type of sentence in the English language is the imperative
>   sentence. Imperative sentences, or imperatives, make commands or
>   requests.  ... Periods and exclamation marks indicate imperative
>   sentences in written English.

Reference - [Sentence Purpose - parentingpatch.com](https://parentingpatch.com/sentence-purpose-declarative-interrogative-imperative-exclamatory/)

The way you can spot that this is imperative is that it ends in a period, and is a request for someone to do something. Whereas an interrogative sentence ends with a question mark.

Comment: Adding to the confusion, there is certainly a chance of using the same words to ask a question for information: "Will you check the tires for me?"