# Question or statement?

Tags: question-mark

This is a passage from a poem:

*What is love, but the passion I feel in my heart?*

*What is passion, but the energy of my soul?*

*What is my soul, but a fountain of emotions erupting?*

My question is, should those lines end with a question mark or period.

Comment: << My question is, should those lines end with a question mark or period. >> should end with a question mark. The three lines of poetry may be either questions the poet wants answering by the reader, or more likely all rhetorical questions. Both require question marks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is it appropriate to end a question without a question mark?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35806/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-question-without-a-question-mark)

Comment: My uncertainty has to do with the "but" conjunction. The sentence appears as a question beginning with "what" but it is answered in the same sentence. Grammarly suggests a question mark. But the sentence is to be read as a statement and not meant to prompt a question in the reader's mind.

Comment: What, other than the energy of my soul. is passion? / Other than the energy of my soul, what could/can passion be?

Comment: @stellarknight How does the existence of *but* actually answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

It's dangerous to apply the grammar of prose to poetry. Here's, the punctuation changes the poet's observations on the nature of love.  With periods, she has solved the mysteries of the heart.  With question marks she at least acknowledges she might be just as lost as the rest of us.

Answer (score 0):

They're rhetorical questions.

And even though they're effectively answering themselves, they're still in the form of a question, so should end with question marks.

Another way to phrase them that makes the questioning nature clearer would be

> Is love anything but than the passion I feel in my heart?
> Is passion anything but the energy of my soul?
> Is my soul anything but a fountain of emotions erupting?